# How to give validation to avoid whitespace in textField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield, whitespace

How to replace this line

```
[txtEmail.textstringByTrimmingCharactersInSet[NSCharacterSetwhitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length == 0`
```

by any function.

```
if ([txtEmail.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length == 0 && 
   [txtPassword.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length == 0)
{

}
else if ([txtEmail.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length == 0)
{

}
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**alternateWay**

```
txtEmail.text = [txtEmail.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

if (txtEmail.text.length == 0)
{
// show alert
}
else
{
 // do your stuff here
}
```

**Option-2**

```
if([txtEmail.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].location!=NSNotFound)
{
NSLog(@"white space Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSRange range = [rawString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:whitespace];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    //whitespace Found.
}
```

Comment: Please use codeblocks (indent by four spaces or press the `{}` button) to format your code.